# Any suggestion for surface mount oscillator (XO) PCB Layout guidelines?

Tags: pcb-design, oscillator

I've searched for PCB Layout guidelines related to surface mount oscillator (XO). I only found A LOT of application notes for oscillators based on pierce-gate topology but not for surface mount oscillator unit.

Are they almost the same ? Is a guard ring also recommended ?

Comment: A surface mount oscillator is an oscillator and not a crystal. Read the details required in the relevant data sheet as to PCB recommendations. There are no generic recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is nothing like a crystal. It is simply an IC which takes in power supply and provides a clock waveform output.

Depending on your module type, the output can be square wave, sine wave, differential LVDS etc.

So standard practices are fine. It needs good bypassing and maybe even some extra filtering, depending on what kind of performance requirements are needed, regarding jitter, phase noise, etc.

For simple usage for a standard logic level square wave oscillator, and depending on the frequency, a single 100nF bypass capacitor might be fine, but manufacturer datasheets and application notes must be taken into account. If the unit has an enable pin, it should be tied high or low to enable it. The clock output pin could benefit from a series resistor for source termination, it also reduces peak currents taken from supply.